# Add minimums to PROC SQL

Tags: sas, proc-sql

Somewhat basic question, how can I attach the minimum of another variable in the PROC SQL step? Is there a better way than PROC SQL?

```
Name   Payment
Tom    30
Tom    45
Tom    15
Bill   20
Bill   100
```

How could I write a  PROC SQL statement that would return the count for each person along with the minimum of "Payment":

```
Name Number MinPayment
Tom  3      15
Bill 2      20
```

Comment: Have you tried the min sql function?

Comment: Yup, worked great! Thanks.

Comment: Proc means/summary/Univariate all work well

Answer (score 3):

```
proc sql;
    select Name
          , count(Name) as Number
          , min(Payment) as MinPayment
    from have
    group by Name
    ;
quit;
```